# Адреса регистров avr в си

Tags: c, avr

В h-файле на конкретный контроллер задефайнены адреса регистров микроконтроллера. Это обычные константы (не указатели).
В программе на си мы пишем что-то типа этого:

```
PORTD = 0xFF;
```

Это перевести весь порт в высокий уровень. Но PORTD это же просто константа. Как компилятор отделяет адреса от простых чисел?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PORTD - это разыменованный указатель на область памяти avr. А выражение `PORTD = 0xFF` - это присваивание значения по указателю. Это аналогично следующему коду

```
byte* p = (byte*)(0x1234);
#define PORTD *p


PORTD = 0xff;
```

в avr это выглядит примерно так

```
define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
define __SFR_OFFSET 0x20
define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
define PORTA   _SFR_IO8(0x02)
```

Comment: В моём дефайне 
    #define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) ((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
Если бы тут был _MMIO_BYTE, то я бы и не спросил.

Comment: Прошу прощения за невнимательность в препроцессоре табы под условиями не делают, потому не заметил, что там этот макрос условный и далее есть правильное определение.